# 12.04 : Three finger gestures disappeared from touchpad?

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, gestures

I've recently upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04, and I realize now that I have lost the ability to simulate a middle-click by using my touchpad with three fingers.

My laptop is a recent Sony VAIO VPCSE (I don't have the precise reference right here).

Is there something to do for me to regain this feature?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue by setting the following configuration values (initial values were 0):

> synclient ClickFinger3=2
>   synclient TapButton3=2

Comment: But of course, the changes are not permanent so I had to make a script. You cannot put it in the standard xorg configuration files, because these are parameters Gnome currently overwrites... See [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/563276).

Comment: Even with a script launched at startup *and* via a crontab, Gnome regularly overwrites this settings...